# Gradle error: "Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined" in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, defined

So I was trying out the material design support library and when I added the dependency, compiled, and I got this error.
I looked at similar problems and tried their solutions but it would not get fixed so I hope you can help me.

Here's my logcat:

```
C:\Users\Jan\AndroidStudioProjects\SwagCalculator3\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.2.0\res\values\values.xml
Error:(1) Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined
```

and here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.raptor.swagcalculator.swagcalculator"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have same issue , after long search I found there are some libraries use the same attribute `rippleColor`

> Example:

1- Google play service

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

2- Design Support Library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

3- MaterialDesign

```
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
```

> Fix this issue

**First** to fix this issue replace **google play service** package (whole package) with specific one you need , please review [google site](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)  as in Google Wallet there attribute called `rippleColor` , in my case all I need google maps `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0`

**Second**  you can replace Design Support Library `compile com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar` with `compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.2'` , if you need to use navigation drawer only

I hope this help

Comment: am also using all above libs except compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' whein i add this in grladle showing rippleColor already defined but where can i find this.

Comment: replace your imports with specific one , replace google play service library with what exactly you need , material navigation with it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.2

Comment: i need navigationdrawer with recyclerview and google maps and gplus sign in and rounded image for list of products and swipeto refresh for scrolldown display refresh icon goodle admob for testing adds

Comment: Is it possible to overwrite RippleColor ?

Comment: I dont think so cause its attribute in library and you cant change it

Answer (score 20):

I found the solution here (https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/289 ). The MaterialDesign Library's rippleColor attritube is replaced with mRippleColor attribute and the compiled library is forked here (https://github.com/vajro/MaterialDesignLibrary).

Adding

```
repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

}

and replacing

```
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
```

with

```
compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'
```

in your build.gradle file should solve the issue.

Comment: why min sdk increased from 10 to 16 in this new library?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that in the projects you are using (your own application + the used libraries) the Attribute named `rippleColor` is used at least two times.

I'd suggest to check through your xml-s containing colors or any attributes (e.g *colors.xml*, or any other, try search for it in the whole project in your IDE).

Check whether the mentioned `rippleColor` is used multiple times. If you have it in your project, rename it!

Comment: I searched everywhere but found it only in the build directory, i dont think i should edit those files ? or should i ?

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem when using [Material Design](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary), this is because "rippleColor" conflicts with android support design package. 
If you downloaded the module and added it as a dependency, you can solved this problem as follows :

1. Press shift-cmd-R to Replace in Path,
2. Text to find : rippleColor
3. Replace with : mrippleColor
4. Check "Whole words only(may be faster)"
5. press "find" button to replace

then click Build-Rebuild to rebuild the project, and it could build successfully.

[image]

Or you can just use this forked library: [link](https://github.com/vajro/MaterialDesignLibrary), he did that replace job for you.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue because I'm using the [MaterialDesign Library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) in my android application where the rippleColor attribute is defined. Here is the example which shows how I've solved this issue.

[image]