# Attribute ”rippleColor“ has already been defined

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, material-design

I am trying to use `MaterialDesignSupport` lib and [MaterialDesignLib](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) (gitHub) 
in the same project

**Gradle Dependcies:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile files('MaterialDesign/libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar') //that jar was missing from some reason
}
```

but i get `Error:(1) Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined`. 
according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31184051) the attr `rippleColor` is mentioned multiple times in the project and i should rename it **but the file that contains the attr is under built folder and it regenerates every time so i can't rename it. Is there a way to rename built files or any way to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different definitions of `rippleColor` in your app, so you'll not be able to compile it because the definitions are built probably in different libraries that you've used.

The only way I see to solve it is copying the code that you need from one of the libraries and avoid copying the `rippleColor` definition.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'`

with `compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'`

and add

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

> **Note:**
>   The aforementioned github repo is a forked version of https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary in which the `rippleColor` attribute has been renamed as `mRippleColor`

Or clone the original repo to desktop (or somewhere) and edit the attribute and use it.