# Error:(1) Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I try to add 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' to my project. But I have error "Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined". It show me path to values.xml, where is attribute occurred. It is in Mike Penz library "MaterialDrawer". But there is a catch, this values.xml does not have any attributes with "rippleColor". Maybe it some bug of gradle or some else? How to fix this?

P.S: when I create new project and add this two libraries (appcompat:design and com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.2) its work fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183193/gradle-error-attribute-ripplecolor-has-already-been-defined-in-android-stud

Comment: "...this values.xml does not have any attributes with "rippleColor""

Comment: You are using a dependency with the same attrs. Check the attrs.xml file.

Comment: it ocurred in myApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.mikepenz/materialdrawer/3.1.2/res/values/values.xml. But, I saw it file, does not have any attributes with "rippleColor".

Comment: do you have other dependencies? i also highly suggest to go with the latest MaterialDrawer and with the latest support design lib and appcompat libs v23.1.0 as they fix a lot of issues. (this will require compileSdk 23 (but target can stay 22))

Answer (score 1):

with this [google search!](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%3A%28%29%20Attribute%20%22rippleColor%22%20has%20already%20been%20defined&oq=Error%3A%28%29%20Attribute%20%22rippleColor%22%20has%20already%20been%20defined&gs_l=serp.3...9443.9443.0.9713.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.Zi-suckfG7g) you can find :

---

It seems that in the projects you are using (your own application + the used libraries) the Attribute named rippleColor is used at least two times.

I'd suggest to check through your xml-s containing colors or any attributes (e.g colors.xml, or any other, try search for it in the whole project in your IDE).

Check whether the mentioned rippleColor is used multiple times. If you have it in your project, rename it!

---

> Example:

1- Google play service

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

2- Design Support Library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

3- MaterialDesign

```
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
```

> Fix this issue

**First** to fix this issue replace **google play service** package (whole package) with specific one you need , please review [google site](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)  as in Google Wallet there attribute called `rippleColor` , in my case all I need google maps `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0`

**Second**  you can replace Design Support Library `compile com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar` with `compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.2'` , if you need to use navigation drawer only

I hope this help