# Show error when added new library too Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want added this library to my project : [Click too see](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) . but when add gradle.build code and click sync button, show me this error and i can't add this library !

Error Message :

[image: here]

I haven't `rippleColor` in `color.xml`, but it reports this error!

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error because `rippleColor` is defined in [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/b11cdc7095473d957a3723fef608d6400a3428ff/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesign/src/main/res/values/attributes.xml#L7) and there are dependences in your project that already defined the same attribute. Please check it in your `build.gradle`. It could be `com.android.support:design` or `com.google.android.gms:play-services`.

The solution is to only include the library you need, instead of adding the whole library.

In my project I use `com.android.support:design` + `com.android.support:appcompat` instead of the material library.

Also see [Gradle error: "Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined" in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183193/gradle-error-attribute-ripplecolor-has-already-been-defined-in-android-stud)

Comment: tnx, how can i added this library to my project?

Comment: Add which library? Please post your ```build.gradle```

Comment: Upload to this lnk : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01969553438155645288   . please help me if you can :(

Comment: You already added design library ```com.android.support:design``` and ```com.android.support:appcompat```, you can use ```Theme.AppCompat``` for material UI, why do you have to add ```MaterialDesignLibrary``` into your project?

Comment: I need to `Slider with number indicator` in this project. how can create or use this? tnx

Comment: Dear @Liuting, can you help me?

Comment: Then see if you can remove the design library, otherwise you have to clone the library, make change on that name and add it as external library to your project. There are lots of people having the same problem:https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/355

Comment: big thanks my dear friend <3 , i want connect you from skype, line , telegram or ... how can i it? tnx