# Attribute "nameHere" has already been defined

Tags: android, gradle

this is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidbelieve.materialnavigationdrawer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'

    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

}
```

But when I build the project I get the following error:
Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined.

I tried to add/remove diferent libraries but no result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183193/gradle-error-attribute-ripplecolor-has-already-been-defined-in-android-stud?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the design support library (`com.android.support:design:22.2.1`) and the MaterialDesign library (`com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar`) define a `rippleColor` attribute.

Given that appcompat and the design support library both provide nearly all Material design components, you probably don't need the third party library and can remove it to fix this error.