# Android "rippleColor" error fix

Tags: android, gradle

I imported [material camera library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera) as library , when i build it i get `Error:(105) Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined` . How to fix it ?

Note: I just created new project and just imported library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183193/gradle-error-attribute-ripplecolor-has-already-been-defined-in-android-stud

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183193/gradle-error-attribute-ripplecolor-has-already-been-defined-in-android-stud